# Is there an efficient way of applying a different function to each element of an array?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Part of my code involves applying different functions to each element of a tensor. For concreteness, say I have:

`f = [f1, f2, ..., fn]`

and

`X = [X1, X2, ..., Xn]`

Here, each element of `f` is a function that takes in a tensor and produces another tensor, and each element of `X` is a tensor.

What I would like to do is compute:

`y = [f1(X1), f2(X2), ..., fn(Xn)]`

The way I have been doing this so far is by using `zip`, i.e.:

`y = [cur_f(cur_x) for cur_f, cur_x in zip(f, X)]`

This works just fine, but it's not very efficient because while each operation *could* be run in parallel, this will run in sequence. Worse, I can't use `tf.function` on this because I am iterating over a tensor, and I don't think I can use `tf.map_fn` because I am looping over functions in the case of `f`.

Is there a nice, fast way of doing this, or is the zip way the only way to go?

Comment: If you do `def apply(p): p[0](p[1])` then the problem is reduced to `map(apply, zip(f, x))`. Is that enough to do it in parallel?

Comment: @kaya3, I don't think this is doing in parallel.

Comment: The built-in `map` doesn't, but I mean that it becomes a regular map where the same function `apply` is applied to each element of the sequence `zip(f, x)`. So if you have a way of doing a map in parallel, it should work so long as you can pass functions to it (as opposed to just data). I don't use tensorflow myself, so I don't know whether `tf.map_fn` allows this.

Comment: you could use pythons threading module. It might be a little too overpowered for this kind of a task